# How can I eliminate the need for http:// to be typed before browsing?

Tags: xcode, macos, http, url, browser

I'm a beginner with Xcode, but I was able to get a simple Mac web browser up and running. It works fine, but it really bothers me that you need to type http:// before each url. For example, I can't just type google.com and hit enter, I need to type http://google.com for it to come up.

Some specifics:
I built the whole app without typing a single line of code. I just used storyboard and linked everything up. You enter your URL in the text field and hit enter, and a WebView displays the page. I am using Xcode 6.

Comment: It's going to take some code.

Answer (score 0):

In the segue triggered by *Enter* you could add `http://` in front programmatically.
This will not completely solve the problem but it won't bother the user anymore.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I am unsure how to find the segue for the enter key.